# NO accounts with iTunes Connect access have been found for the team "xyz".itunes Connect access is required for App Store distribution

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ad-hoc-distribution, xcode9.4

I am able to login with Xcode under preference but when I try to upload my app I am getting above error.
 I have tried many options like reopen Xcode and login many time with a developer account,
but I couldn't succeed. can anyone help me out this?

Comment: have you tried iTunes login?

Comment: yes I have tried it too.

Comment: so it is login success I think. so check in the Users and Roles section, for your user role. is it admin?

Comment: its showing as user

Comment: check your login role

Comment: where to check login role

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177352/discussion-between-piyushrathi-and-suniel-kalwani).

Answer (score -1):

All I can say is good luck getting to the bottom of this. I've been dealing with it for 2+ months. It comes and goes in all 3 of the apps I publish. I've tried dozens of things that supposedly fix it, but it seems to just fix itself at random times when I've changed nothing. So if it's not working now, try it again in a few hours and it'll likely magically work again. I worked with Apple tech support for over a week and they got nowhere with it. Every time they'd dig into it at all, it would work for me and they'd say contact them again when it's not working.